# Flash content not loading

Tags: iis, joomla

I've hosted a website on IIS. This website has a image slider done using flash and this flash content loads only when the website is bound to port 80.It is not working on any of the other ports.I've assigned port 85 to this website and the flash content is not loading.

Platform Details

1)Windows server 2012,IIS 8,Joomla,php.

Note:
It is working perfectly on port 80.

Comment: Does all other plugins/ modules/ etc works fine on 85 port?

Comment: yes everything works fine except this flash content.

Comment: This is my Website address : www.alessamedicare.com/medicare/ - now this website is bound to port 80 where you can see the flash image slider working fine in the home screen .when I bind the same website to port 85 the flash content is not loading.

Comment: have you checked your console after changing port.?@Borg

Comment: I can't understand your question.can you please elaborate? Thank you for your response @SumitPathak

Comment: i mean that after changing port you run your site and then check your console errors like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Borg Pretty good clean design, mate. Well, there is no point to show us normal working site- try to change port again, and look to browser console (we'll be looking too :)